# Adding smoother to ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used the following code to create a plot in r using ggplot2:

```
g <- ggplot(newdata, aes(MVPAper, FMI) +
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm'))
```

I then added the following:

```
p <- g + geom_point(aes(color = Age)) + 
     facet_grid(Age ~ .) + 
     stat_smooth(method = 'lm') + 
     theme_bw(base_family = 'Times')`
```

I am wanting to have a smoother for each of the four graphs I have created, using the facet grid to split the graph into four ages 8,9,12,and 15) can anyone assist with my code?

Comment: You should add a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both `geom_smooth()` and `stat_smooth()`. Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- diamonds %>% filter(price < 10000, carat < 2.5)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(carat, price, color = cut))

g + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  facet_grid(cut ~ .) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]